# How to parse a string given the following?

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7

I'm new with python, given this list:

```
a_list=['''('string','string'),...,('string','string'), 'STRING' ''']
```

How can I drop the quotes, parenthesis, and leaving out 'STRING' in order to get a string like this:

```
string string ... string
```

This is what I all ready tried:

```
new_list = ''.join( c for c in ''.join(str(v) for v
                                              in a_list)
                           if c not in ",'()")
print new_list
```

Comment: Does your string actually have a `...`, or are you using that to represent more strings?

Comment: Im trying to avoid regex

Comment: @senshin yes it's a very large string, im using it to represent more strings

Comment: The way you wrote it down, it's a list with 1 item: a string. This string has some parentheses and commas but it is essentially one string. Once you understand this, you can try to remove the unnecessary values such as comas, dots or parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string doesn't have a literal `...`, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) here. That will convert your string into a tuple (whose elements are 2-tuples and strings), since it basically is the string representation of a tuple. After that, it's a simple matter of iterating over the tuple and converting it to the form you want.

```
>>> import ast
>>> x = '''('string','string'), ('string2','string3'), ('string','string'), 'STRING' '''
>>> y = ast.literal_eval(x); print(y)
(('string', 'string'), ('string2', 'string3'), ('string', 'string'), 'STRING')
>>> ' '.join( ' '.join(elem) if type(elem) is tuple else '' for elem in y )
'string string string2 string3 string string '
```

Comment: I would not like to use other libraries any other idea?, plus i got malformed string. Thanks

Comment: @newWithPython Why do you not want to use any other libraries?

Comment: Because im starting with python and i would like to see an example of how manipulate strings.

Comment: @newWithPython The correct way to solve this problem is to use `ast.literal_eval` or something similar. If you want to solve this without using external libraries, you will basically find yourself reimplementing a buggy version of `ast.literal_eval`. If you want to do that, more power to you, but I have no other suggestions to offer. If you're getting a malformed string error, update your question with additional details about your string.

Comment: Im geting malformed string error with your solution im not using the interpreter.

Comment: @newWithPython What do you mean by "not using the interpreter"?

Comment: I done the followin: `import ast
x = [''' ('string','string'), ('string2','string3'), ('string','string'), 'STRING' ''']
y = ast.literal_eval(x); print(y)
list_=[' '.join( ' '.join(elem) if type(elem) is tuple else '' for elem in y )]
print list`

Comment: @newWithPython You added `[]` around the string, thus turning it into a list. Remove the square brackets, or access `x[0]` instead of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the other answer is the perfect one, But as you wanted to learn more about string techniques rather than using the present libraries then this will also work.

Do note that this is a **VERY BAD** way to solve your problem.

```
a_list=['''('string','string'),...,('string','string'), 'STRING' ''']
new_list = []
for i in a_list:
    j = i.replace("'",'')
    j = j.replace('(','')
    j = j.replace(')','')
    j = j.replace(',',' ')
    j = j.replace('STRING','')  
    j = j.strip()
    new_list.append(j)

print new_list
```

It will output

```
'string string ... string string'
```